# facebook.ads.InterstitialAdActivity Activity null pointer ex

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-audience-network

Exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{my.app.package/com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I saw an Exception with Facebook InterstitialAd Activity in my Android Application.

Do you have any idea for this null pointer ex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Nope, it's not same with that question. It's about facebook Ads Activity. It's not my fault. I asked this question maybe anybody solve the same problem. Thx.

Comment: If you think the Audience Network SDK contains a bug, you can report it to facebook at developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same.  Try updating to a later Audience Network SDK, e.g. 4.9.0, which fixes some issues:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x

> Fixed
>
> - Fixed bug related to detached surface texture causing
> - IllegalStateException. Fixed bug causing crashes if ad title was null.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough information for diagnosing the issue. Please provide a code snippet showing how the activity is called.
In general, to use the Interstitial Ad, you have to declare the InterstitialAdActivity first in the manifest file:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name">

  ...

  <activity android:name="com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
</application>
```